# How to keep a local file different from the git remote?

Tags: git

Currently I'm working with a team on a project. Due to some reasons my computer needs some special settings so I want to keep a local file different from git remote, which won't be uploaded when I git push. What should I do?

I guess I may need to do some modifications in .gitignore, but that will have a global effect.

Answer (score 0):

There's no solution for this built into Git.

One solution is to `git stash` your locally-modified version of the file before merging or rebasing, and then restoring it after the merge:

```bash
# Stash your local changes
git stash -m 'Preserve local changes.' -- the-special-file.conf

# Merge, rebase, whatever you need to do
git pull

# Un-stash your local changes
git stash pop
```

You can package this up into a script or Git alias, but keep in mind that you run the risk of creating a conflict between your local version of the file and the remote version. You might have to spend a while resolving conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

Two common ways to have local settings described in a file, not shared with the repo:

- have your whole config unversioned :
  instead of committing *the config file*, commit *a template*, place the config file in gitignore list, have each developper create a local config from template
- have a way to load a local config file:
  add some way to say `include: config-local.conf` in your shared conf (which doesn't fail if file is missing), put `config-local.conf` in gitignore list, overload configuration settings in `config-local.conf`

We're using the second option and are very happy with it.